# SDL 2.0 - SDL_GameControllerGetButton not working

Tags: c++, qt, sdl, joystick, gamecontroller

I am developing an application that needs to display which buttons are pressed on a joystick.

For this, I used SDL to read the state of my joysticks, the code is:

```
bool JoystickInfo::getButton (const int &joystick, SDL_GameControllerButton button)
{
    SDL_JoystickUpdate();
    gameController_ = SDL_GameControllerOpen (joystick);
    return (bool) SDL_GameControllerGetButton (gameController_, button);
}
```

For some reason, this function always returns 0 (false). I have also tried using the SDL events (as shown [here](http://blog.5pmcasual.com/game-controller-api-in-sdl2.html), but I also got the same result.

Side-notes:

- The code above worked fine with SDL 1.2, but I need SDL 2.0 for the `GameController` API.
- I read the values of the axes of my joystick in a similar way and it works without any issue.
- `SDL_INIT()` is called with `SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING`.

The code that I use for reading axis values is:

```
double JoystickInfo::getAxis (const int &joystick, SDL_GameControllerAxis axis)
{
    SDL_JoystickUpdate();
    gameController_ = SDL_GameControllerOpen (joystick);
    return (double) SDL_GameControllerGetAxis (gameController_, axis);
}
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Can you post how you successfully read the controller axis values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by loading controller mappings from a file (such as the [SDL_GameControllerDB](https://github.com/gabomdq/SDL_GameControllerDB/blob/master/gamecontrollerdb.txt)).

Some useful links:

- https://github.com/gabomdq/SDL_GameControllerDB
- http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GameControllerAddMappingsFromFile
- http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GameControllerAddMapping